# How do I solve the problem with connect directly this url?

Tags: wordpress

Recently my boss ask me to solve this issue

My problem is if i click any templates of this page

The url will work . But went I type the same or paste url on the url bar of the chrome  the page will show the 404 alert

Here is the page

https://www.design-hu.com/web-design/template

As far as I know  this website was built by Wordpress and the templates was created by the Wordpress's plugin  WP - portfolio

And here is official website of  WP - portfolio

https://wpportfolio.net/.

I’m not good at writing  ..

If is there any question  please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their docs seem to address this issue here:

https://wpportfolio.net/docs/no-items-found-message-flush-the-permalinks/

And the steps they say to follow are to go into setting > permalinks and click "save changes"

**Edit**:

Seeing as that solution did not work in this case, it seems that the next solution is to add a rewrite rule.

Wpportfolio may have created the URL artificially and WP doesn't know what to do with it.

In the functions.php file at the very end you can add the following:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my-custom-function' );
function my-custom-function(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'webdesign/template?([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=this-pages-name',
        'top' );
}
```

Replace this-pages-name with the actual name of the page that contains the list of templates (/webdesign/template)

Then the first answer, flushing the permalinks, do that again.

This *should* reroute /webdesign/template?template=27 to /webdesign/template on the server side and then the JavaScript code on the client side *should* take over and add the template back to the view.

I don't write php or develop WordPress sites, so definitely test this first and it may need some tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll try to dig a little deeper and get back to you.